# Redirect only when no subdirectories are selected

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm trying to to redirect on *xyz.sample.com* to *www.sample.com/order/xyz*, which works fine, but  the problem is now that resources like *xyz.sample.com/js/file.js* redirects to *www.sample.com/order/xyz/js/file.js* which is no right, how can i only do the redirection when the url is just *xyz.sample.com* and im not trying to access anything inside, below is my rewrite rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite service provider to web ordering page" enabled="true"  stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*)\.sample\.com$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^manage\.sample\.com$" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="order/{C:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be mod_rewrite (as in [Apache's mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)). Could you please update your question with the thing you are using?

Comment: @Sumurai8 it's iis7 rewrite

Comment: I've made a quick edit to your question (you can do this yourself via the edit link at the bottom of the post). I don't know anything about iis, but I hope other people can find it easier this way ;-)